# Find and replace with regex by defining beginning and end of string

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

How would I replace in PhpStorm (it is not important I guess) all occurrences of (selecting string which starts with `{!!` and ends with `!!}`):

`{!! $arr['my.key.1234'] !!}`
to `{!! $arr('my.key.1234') !!}`
(note change in braces)

I tried to select the key with this regex: 
`\{\!\! \$arr\[.*.] !!}`  which works but how do I now replace it?

EDIT:

I only want to select array key which is variable so my regex doesn't work - it selects whole line.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot it's a function to replace which I do not need (sorry for confusing question) - what I want is to write an expression which allows me to replace square brackets for round brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PhpStorm, open the replace dialogue and make sure you've checked the Regex checkbox.

For your find, you can use:

```
(\{!!\s*\$\w+)\[('[\w\.]+')\](\s*!!\})
```

This captures the 3 parts you want to keep. You then replace the brackets and use `$1`, `$2` and `$3` to insert your original content around the new brackets.

```
$1($2)$3
```

Screenshot of how to do this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can search like this with phpstorm:

- `(\{\!\!.+\$.+)(\[)` replace by `$1(`
- `(])(.*\!\!}$)` replace by `)$2`

Don't forget to check the box `regex` in search toolbar.

Comment: When I use first replacement expression - the second expression does not match pattern but that's to be expected.

Comment: Strange, for me it works, i use first replacement to put `(` and the second replacement to put `)` works also.